# Multiple page PDF with multiple charts per page from matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, pdf-generation

How can I do multiple page PDF with multiple charts per page from matplotlib to PDF?

There is a great example for chart per page into multiple page PDF:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html

**How can I do for example 8 charts per portrait page? Or better 1 to 8 on grid of 8** because number of charts is usually not exact multiple of 8 in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was obviously not looking good enough before. All what is needed is to change in the example I mentioned in my question:

```
plt.figure()
```

into:

```
plt.subplot()
```

With subplot it is possible to split page into grid and add charts into grid positions.